# Documento docx generado con OpenXML a pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, docx, openxml

He generado un documento docx con OPENXML, en una aplicación web con c#,  pero ahora el cliente necesita un PDF.

¿Es posible generar un documento pdf desde un docx, sin tener MS OFFICE instalado OpenXML y de forma gratuita?

Comment: Igual puedes intentar utilizar algún conversor online para esta tarea.

Comment: Si encuentras alguna solución coméntala, Gracias :)